# Is dram constantly refreshing during windows sleeps?

Tags: sdram

I know that sram and dram are volatile so even when windows is in sleep mode(not hibernation, in which memory is backed up to secondary storage), but I'm curious whether dram is constantly refreshing. I'm pretty sure about this because otherwise dram wouldn't be able to store information, but I can't find any source regarding this. Also, if so, is dram refeshing mechanism the only part where computer consumes power during sleep mode?

Comment: related:- https://superuser.com/questions/1101623/what-happens-when-you-go-to-sleep-mode-in-windows-10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern DRAM such as SDRAM, DDR ... DDR4 have an "automatic self refresh mode" where the memory just need to be powered to internally manage periodic refresh cycles. The rest of the computer can be powered down to save energy.

In that mode, DRAM draws about half the normal idle current and 1/5 to 1/10 of the current drawn during reads.

(DRAM refresh period is in the order of 20ms, so it's impractical to periodically awake the computer just to refresh DRAM.)

Answer (score 0):

Simple rule: If DRAM is holding data you care about, you need to be refreshing it. If there were a way to not refresh DRAM...we would be not refreshing it all the time.